# Unit testing a DAO class that uses Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, testing, dao, jdbctemplate

I have several DAO objects that are used to retrieve information from a database and I *really* want to write some automated tests for them but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

I'm using Spring's `JdbcTemplate` to run the actual query (via a prepared statement) and map the results to the model object (via the `RowMapper` class).

If I were to write unit tests, I'm not sure how I would/should mock the objects. For example, since there are only reads, I would use the actual database connection and not mock the jdbcTemplate, but I'm not sure that's right.

Here's the (simplified) code for the simplest DAO of the batch:

```
/**
 * Implementation of the {@link BusinessSegmentDAO} interface using JDBC.
 */
public class GPLBusinessSegmentDAO implements BusinessSegmentDAO {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static class BusinessSegmentRowMapper implements RowMapper<BusinessSegment>  {
        public BusinessSegment mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException { 
            try {
                return new BusinessSegment(rs.getString(...));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class GetBusinessSegmentsPreparedStatementCreator 
        implements PreparedStatementCreator {
        private String region, cc, ll;
        private int regionId;

        private GetBusinessSegmentsPreparedStatementCreator(String cc, String ll) {
            this.cc = cc;
            this.ll = ll;
        }

        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
                throws SQLException {           
            String sql = "SELECT ...";

            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, cc);
            ps.setString(2, ll);
            return ps;
        }
    }

    public GPLBusinessSegmentDAO(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public Collection<BusinessSegment> getBusinessSegments(String cc, String ll) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                new GetBusinessSegmentsPreparedStatementCreator(cc, ll), 
                new BusinessSegmentRowMapper());
    }

}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You could have a look at [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/), a framework to unit test the JDBC persistence, with real isolation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please have a look at below links:

1. [Testing SQL queries with Spring and DbUnit](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2010/02/04/Testing-SQL-queries-with-Spring-and-DbUnit,-part-1)
2. [MockObjects or DBUnit for testing Code using JdbcTemplate](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=10280)

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

Here is the [GitHub version of RowMapperTests](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/3.1.x/org.springframework.jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapperTests.java) for easy reference.

Comment: Now that SpringSource has moved to github, you can find RowMapperTests **[here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/tree/3.1.x/org.springframework.jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core)**. EDIT: I have updated the answer with the new link.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend breaking your dependency on `JdbcTemplate` class, and using the `JdbcOperations` interface instead, e.g.

```
public class GPLBusinessSegmentDAO implements BusinessSegmentDAO {
    private final JdbcOperations jdbc;

    public GPLBusinessSegmentDAO(DataSource dataSource) {
        this(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
    }

    public GPLBusinessSegmentDAO(JdbcOperations jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = jdbc;
    }

    // ... DAO methods here
}
```

Your unit test can invoke the second constructor, passing in a mock `JdbcOperations` object.  Since all DB operations are performed via the `jdbc` object, you can mock that easily enough.

Your live code can call the first constructor as before.

Answer (score 2):

To write a true unit test for this, you would not be touching a real database.
You may however find it more practical to pass in a real DataSource to your underlying db, and test the getBusinessSegments() method returns 0, 1 and many results depending on the cc and ll values you pass in.

Another option worth investigating would be to pass in a DataSource of an embedded [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) that was initialised with your schema in a setUp/@Before method. I guess what you really want to test is that the SELECT... query maps correctly to the schema, so such a test would catch any errors that arise at runtime when the schema, say, changes.